# Is it possible to include 2 html pages in the same php file?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `index.php` file and I'm trying to include the header and footer (html files) in it. They are both bootstrap based and I just made a few customizations in `header.html`. If I include only the header file there's no problems at all and `index.php` is displayed as expect but when I include both files (hearder/footer.html), for some reason, my css doesn't display the changes (only displays the default values of the bootstrap). This is the problem I would like to solve. I will ask another question too:

1. I have several pages that have the same header and footer. The goal here is not repeating code. Is this the better way to include
   these elements (header/footer)? Am I doing it right?

   These are the files I'm using:

   - [This pen](http://codepen.io/henry/pen/VKyrgE) shows the modifications that should be displayed in the index.php file.
   - [This file](http://pastebin.com/euBiYB39) represents the main file (index.php)
   - [This file](http://pastebin.com/s64KFqc7) contains the header.html
   - [This file](http://pastebin.com/xeLcC4fw) contains the footer.html

I realized that if I comment the include of `footer.html` in the main file `index.php` it's content is displayed and everything works right.

Comment: your creating an invalid html file

Comment: Can you be more specific please? @nogad

Comment: your header and footer files contain "<!DOCTYPE html>" etc.. they should not be full files, just the snippets of html you need. Include is just copy\paste. View the finial file (even better validate it:https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Sure, but I think that's irrelevant since the browser comments those pieces of code and therefore ignores them. I tried to that before and the problem still persists.

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: As nogad says, and as seen in the solutions below, your final file should only have one `doctype` declaration (it's not a comment), one `head`, and one `body`. It might be helpful for you to think about it like this: start with the final file, and then cut and paste reused chunks into their own files and then add the `include()`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Your **footer.html also includes CSS stylesheets which override the header.html's stylesheets.**

You can do something like this

*Header.html

```
<html>
<head>
 add all the stylesheets here or combine them
</head>
<body>
<navigation>
</navigation>
```

*footer.html

```
<footer information goes here>
add javascript here

</body>
</html>
```

*index.php

```
include ('header.html')

content goes here

include('footer.html')
```

Comment: Well I tried to combine all the stylesheets of the footer on the <head> of the header.html but that didn't worked. Btw, those CSS stylesheets that footer includes are the stylesheets related to the sticky footer.

Comment: @snobis: Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Header and footer are resetting the CSS when loaded. You only need to link your CSS in the header. Think of it as creating 1 document out of 3, you only need to reference the material once.

Use this PHP to include your files and then fix your HTML files

```
<?php 
    require_once ('header.html');
?>

//do stuff

<?php 
    require_once('footer.html'); 
?>
```

> In your header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Header</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">         

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/navbar.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-WDM-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="../img/fb_favicon.jpg">
                 </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-WDM-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="./index.php">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./about.php">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./projects.php">projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./contact.php">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

> HERE IS WHERE YOUR MAIN BODY CONTENT WOULD BE PLACED

```
//Do Stuff
```

> In your footer

```
footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>Copyrights</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p>links here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>  
        </body>
    </html>
```